# JQuery UI Sortable Disabled Scroll on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Fiddle - http://jsbin.com/asaVUmAP/1/edit

I've been working on a website designer application, and today I added the ability to sort dialogs in a properties panel. My app is built for both desktop and touch devices. (I'm also using [JQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/))

After I applied JQuery UI's sortable I tested it out on my iPod, and I can no longer scroll in a div contained in ".sort div". Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Here's the code I'm using...

```
$('.sort-container').sortable({placeholder: "ui-state-highlight", helper:'clone', cancel: ".sort div"});
```

Comment: Other than you calling it a fiddle, I see no problem with this code.  I just used it on my phone too.  Works great.  Lemme know when the finished product comes out so I can swipe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### OK done.

I went a little overboard and started fixing other stuff too...some of which you'll probably change like the page height, etc.  I did that so you can scroll the whole bar without being super exact, while still being able to scroll the tiny boxes AND sort them.

***[JSBin Code](http://jsbin.com/asaVUmAP/5/edit)***
**[JSBin Demo - use on iPhone](http://jsbin.com/asaVUmAP/5/)**

### Javascript:

```
// Toggle Dialog Visibility
$(".dialogname").toggle(function () {
    $(this).next().slideUp();
    $(this).html("&nbsp; &#x25b6;" + $(this).attr('title'));
}, function () {
    $(this).next().slideDown();
    $(this).html("&nbsp; &#x25bc;" + $(this).attr('title'));
});

$('.sort-container').sortable({
    items: '> .sort',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    helper: "clone",
    scroll: true
});
$('.dialog').on('click mousedown mouseover select touchstart touchmove', function (evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event;
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

### CSS:

```
body {
    background:#ccc;
    height: 100%;
}
.sort-container {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: #202020;
}
.dialog {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 150px;
    color: #ccc;
    background: #333;
    overflow: auto;
}
.dialog textarea {
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    top:5%;
    left:5%;
    height:90%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.dialogname {
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

There's a lot of HTML, really not a necessary part of this since I didn't change any of it.

*Hope this helps :)*

Comment: Thank you. If you want to try the website designer out you can head to - http://mydelivery.net23.net/dev/MMD/app/. I also hosted it on GitHub (https://github.com/mikethedj4/Mobile-Website-Designer) as well.